# Laravel - Eager Loading Polymorphic Relation's Related Models

Tags: laravel, eloquent, polymorphic-associations, eager-loading, polymorphism

I can eager load polymorphic relations/models without any n+1 issues. However, if I try to access a model related to the polymorphic model, the n+1 problem appears and I can't seem to find a fix. Here is the exact setup to see it locally:

**1) DB table name/data**

`history`

[image: history table]
    `companies`

[image]
    `products`

[image]
    `services`

[image]

**2) Models**

```
// History
class History extends Eloquent {
    protected $table = 'history';

    public function historable(){
        return $this->morphTo();
    }
}

// Company
class Company extends Eloquent {
    protected $table = 'companies';

    // each company has many products
    public function products() {
        return $this->hasMany('Product');
    }

    // each company has many services
    public function services() {
        return $this->hasMany('Service');
    }
}

// Product
class Product extends Eloquent {
    // each product belongs to a company
    public function company() {
        return $this->belongsTo('Company');
    }

    public function history() {
        return $this->morphMany('History', 'historable');
    }
}

// Service
class Service extends Eloquent {
    // each service belongs to a company
    public function company() {
        return $this->belongsTo('Company');
    }

    public function history() {
        return $this->morphMany('History', 'historable');
    }
}
```

**3) Routing**

```
Route::get('/history', function(){
    $histories = History::with('historable')->get();
    return View::make('historyTemplate', compact('histories'));
});
```

**4) Template with n+1 logged only becacuse of $history->historable->company->name, comment it out, n+1 goes away.. but we need that distant related company name:**

```
@foreach($histories as $history)
    <p>
        <u>{{ $history->historable->company->name }}</u>
        {{ $history->historable->name }}: {{ $history->historable->status }}
    </p>
@endforeach
{{ dd(DB::getQueryLog()); }}
```

I need to be able to load the company names eagerly (in a single query) as it's a related model of the polymorphic relation models `Product` and `Service`.
I’ve been working on this for days but can't find a solution.
`History::with('historable.company')->get()` just ignores the `company` in `historable.company`.
What would an efficient solution to this problem be?

Comment: you can eager load `Company` model dynamically by `$historables->load('company')`

Comment: @Razor I added an update, where would your suggestion go to eager load `Company`?

Answer (score 78, accepted):

**Solution:**

It is possible, if you add:

```php
protected $with = ['company'];
```

to both the `Service` and `Product` models. That way, the `company` relation is eager-loaded every time a `Service` or a `Product` is loaded, including when loaded via the polymorphic relation with `History`.

---

**Explanation:**

This will result in an additional 2 queries, one for `Service` and one for `Product`, i.e. one query for each `historable_type`. So your total number of queries—regardless of the number of results `n`—goes from `m+1` (without eager-loading the distant `company` relation) to `(m*2)+1`, where `m` is the number of models linked by your polymorphic relation.

---

**Optional:**

The downside of this approach is that you will *always* eager-load the `company` relation on the `Service` and `Product` models. This may or may not be an issue, depending on the nature of your data. If this is a problem, you could use this trick to automatically eager-load `company` *only* when calling the polymorphic relation.

Add this to your `History` model:

```php
public function getHistorableTypeAttribute($value)
{
    if (is_null($value)) return ($value); 
    return ($value.'WithCompany');
}
```

Now, when you load the `historable` polymorphic relation, Eloquent will look for the classes `ServiceWithCompany` and `ProductWithCompany`, rather than `Service` or `Product`. Then, create those classes, and set `with` inside them:

**ProductWithCompany.php**

```php
class ProductWithCompany extends Product {
    protected $table = 'products';
    protected $with = ['company'];
}
```

**ServiceWithCompany.php**

```php
class ServiceWithCompany extends Service {
    protected $table = 'services';
    protected $with = ['company'];
}
```

...and finally, you can remove `protected $with = ['company'];` from the base `Service` and `Product` classes.

A bit hacky, but it should work.

Comment: The edit with extending the class made all the difference, as it calls it only when the polymorphic needs it, not everywhere everytime. Thanks for this great workaraound damiani. Since it extends the original class(es) we can remove `$table` from the extended class. I again hope Taylor allows us to query it easily like other relations like this `$histories = History::with('historable.company')->get();` Thanks again damiani :)

Comment: Note that you can remove `$table` only if you declared it explicitly on the parent model; if you didn't, then the polymorphic call will be looking for the table `product_with_company`. This load-distant-relation functionality would be a useful addition to Laravel, though it's a bit complicated since it assumes that the same relation (`company`) is available on all morphed models.

Comment: Yeah - of course it's explicitly stated in the parent model :) I requested it on github from Taylor - waiting to see his thoughts on this as it would be awesome to eager load it like other models. Specially if we explicitly call it, it *should* work if it exists, otherwise, throw an error. Would be a great addition to Laravel.

Comment: Just wondering about `getHistorableTypeAttribute` where did you discover this. I can't seem to find information about it. Any online resource(s)?

Comment: It's an *accessor*, and there's a very short description of them in the docs at http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/eloquent#accessors-and-mutators. It's a function that gets performed on an attribute (i.e. on a field from your database) whenever it's accessed; `getFooAttribute` will be performed whenever the `foo` property is accessed, and `$this->foo` will be set to whatever value is returned from the accessor.

Comment: Pretty interesting, it's a buried gem. Thanks for pointing it out damiani :)

Comment: awesome! Just solved an issue with Polymorphic in L5.1!!

Comment: Genius, I never would have considered extending a third time!

Answer (score 10):

You can separate the collection, then lazy eager load each one:

```php
$histories =  History::with('historable')->get();

$productCollection = new Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection();
$serviceCollection = new Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection();

foreach($histories as $history){
     if($history->historable instanceof Product)
          $productCollection->add($history->historable);
     if($history->historable instanceof Service)
        $serviceCollection->add($history->historable);
}
$productCollection->load('company');
$serviceCollection->load('company');

// then merge the two collection if you like
foreach ($serviceCollection as $service) {
     $productCollection->push($service);
}
$results = $productCollection;
```

Probably it's not the best solution, adding `protected $with = ['company'];` as suggested by @damiani is as good solution, but it depends on your business logic.

Comment: Great answer Razor. This and damiani's answer are great workarounds and both work, but I like how damiani extracted it out as a class extension keeping the route/controller clean, so I'll go for his answer. I really wish Taylor Otwell is able to add the syntax to laravel and simply call it like this `$histories = History::with('historable.company')->get();` Thanks for your great answer - upvoted!

Answer (score 5):

Pull Request [#13737](https://github.com/laravel/framework/pull/13737) and [#13741](https://github.com/laravel/framework/pull/13741) fixed this issue.

Just update your Laravel version and the following code

```
protected $with = [‘likeable.owner’];
```

Will work as expected.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% sure on this, because it's hard to re-create your code in my system but perhaps `belongTo('Company')` should be `morphedByMany('Company')`. You could also try `morphToMany`. I was able to get a complex polymorphic relationship to load properly without multiple calls. ?

Comment: Not sure, I will put together more details early tomorrow so people can easy reproduce the issue locally, so it's easier to see it. It would be amazing to get it to work.

Comment: Not sure at all... `morphToMany` and `morphedByMany` are used in a **many to many** polymorphic relation, which is not the case and requires a different table structure.

Comment: Updated question to be easily reproducible.

Answer (score -1):

As João Guilherme mentioned, this was fixed in version 5.3  However, I've found myself facing the same bug in an App where it's not feasible to upgrade.  So I've created an override method that will apply the fix to Legacy APIs.  (Thanks João, for pointing me in the right direction to produce this.)

First, create your Override class:

```
namespace App\Overrides\Eloquent;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\MorphTo as BaseMorphTo;

/**
 * Class MorphTo
 * @package App\Overrides\Eloquent
 */
class MorphTo extends BaseMorphTo
{
    /**
     * Laravel < 5.2 polymorphic relationships fail to adopt anything from the relationship except the table. Meaning if
     * the related model specifies a different database connection, or timestamp or deleted_at Constant definitions,
     * they get ignored and the query fails.  This was fixed as of Laravel v5.3.  This override applies that fix.
     *
     * Derived from https://github.com/laravel/framework/pull/13741/files and
     * https://github.com/laravel/framework/pull/13737/files.  And modified to cope with the absence of certain 5.3
     * helper functions.
     *
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    protected function getResultsByType($type)
    {
        $model = $this->createModelByType($type);
        $whereBindings = \Illuminate\Support\Arr::get($this->getQuery()->getQuery()->getRawBindings(), 'where', []);
        return $model->newQuery()->withoutGlobalScopes($this->getQuery()->removedScopes())
            ->mergeWheres($this->getQuery()->getQuery()->wheres, $whereBindings)
            ->with($this->getQuery()->getEagerLoads())
            ->whereIn($model->getTable().'.'.$model->getKeyName(), $this->gatherKeysByType($type))->get();
    }
}
```

Next, you'll need something that lets your Model classes actually talk to your incarnation of MorphTo rather than Eloquent's.  This can be done by either a trait applied to each model, or a child of Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model that gets extended by your model classes instead of Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model directly.  I chose to make this into a trait.  But in case you chose to make it a child class, I've left in the part where it infers the name as a heads-up that that's something you'd need to consider:

```
<?php

namespace App\Overrides\Eloquent\Traits;

use Illuminate\Support\Str;
use App\Overrides\Eloquent\MorphTo;

/**
 * Intended for use inside classes that extend Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model
 *
 * Class MorphPatch
 * @package App\Overrides\Eloquent\Traits
 */
trait MorphPatch
{
    /**
     * The purpose of this override is just to call on the override for the MorphTo class, which contains a Laravel 5.3
     * fix.  Functionally, this is otherwise identical to the original method.
     *
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function morphTo($name = null, $type = null, $id = null)
    {
        //parent::morphTo similarly infers the name, but with a now-erroneous assumption of where in the stack to look.
        //So in case this App's version results in calling it, make sure we're explicit about the name here.
        if (is_null($name)) {
            $caller = last(debug_backtrace(DEBUG_BACKTRACE_IGNORE_ARGS, 2));
            $name = Str::snake($caller['function']);
        }

        //If the app using this trait is already at Laravel 5.3 or higher, this override is not necessary.
        if (version_compare(app()::VERSION, '5.3', '>=')) {
            return parent::morphTo($name, $type, $id);
        }

        list($type, $id) = $this->getMorphs($name, $type, $id);

        if (empty($class = $this->$type)) {
            return new MorphTo($this->newQuery(), $this, $id, null, $type, $name);
        }

        $instance = new $this->getActualClassNameForMorph($class);
        return new MorphTo($instance->newQuery(), $this, $id, $instance->getKeyName(), $type, $name);
    }
}
```