# Laravel Distant many to many relationship

Tags: php, laravel-4, eloquent

***Schema***:
**Media**:
id,
mediable_id,
mediable_type,
name

**Categories**
id,
parent_id,
name,

**Articles**
id,
title,
description,
author_id, and some other meta data fields

**articles_categories**
article_id,
category_id,

**users**
id,
name,
email,
pass

**Relations**:

1. Articles and Categories: Many to Many
2. Articles and Media: Polymorphic One to Many
3. Categories to Media: Polymorphic One to Many
4. Articles to Users: One to One

I tried various approach as suggested by damiani at [Laravel - Eager Loading Polymorphic Relation's Related Models](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26727088/laravel-eager-loading-polymorphic-relations-related-models), but somehow I am not able to eager-load the media for the articles and categories.

```
$articles = Categories->with(array('user', 'media','articles' => function($query)
    {
        $query->where('articles.is_featured', '=', 1)
            ->where('articles.status', '=', 1)
            ->where('published_at', '>=', new \DateTime('today'))   
            ->orderBy('created_at', 'desc');

    }));
```

I also tried:
    $articles = Categories->with('articles', 'articles.media', 'articles.user');

Comment: Just add `articles.media` to the `with` array.

Comment: I had tried that already with no luck.

Comment: define `with no luck`. It's hard to help you if you don't tell us what you tried and what was the output vs. the output you expected.

Comment: Thanks Jarek! I read a bit more about it and found the expected result. There was no issue with the code but I was confusing between the JOIN and Eager loaded objects. I was just debugging the SQL output to see if the media table is being referenced but obviously that was the wrong approach. I get the articles objects in the `foreach` loop of ` $categories` , while to get the media related to an article I had to loop through the `$articles->media as $medias `.

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by Jarek and other stackoverflow users I needed to include another reference with the `with` static call, my code is:

```
$articles = Category::with(array('articles.media','articles' => function($query)
    {
        $query->where('articles.is_featured', '=', 1)
            ->where('articles.status', '=', 1)
            ->where('published_at', '<=', new \DateTime('today'))   
            ->orderBy('created_at', 'desc');

    }));
```

And this is how I get the desired data:

```
foreach($categories as $category){
        echo "<hr>Category Information: ".$category->id."  :  ".$category->name;
        foreach($category->articles as $article){
            echo "--<br>Article ID is: ".$article->id;
            foreach($article->media as $media){
                echo "----<br>Image: ".$media->name;
            }
        }
    }
```

I hope I am using the correct solution.